# soap fails after implementing applicationContext.xml

Tags: java, soap, playframework

I'm developing a backend `REST API` with Play Framework. I have integrated some `SOAP` services from an external company and everything works fine.

Now I need to create a `SOAP` endpoint following this tutorial : http://www.imind.eu/web/2013/11/07/developing-soap-services-using-play-framework-2-2-x/ and all other `SOAP` services now fail with the following error:

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[SOAPFaultException: Play! Transport doesn't support client operation mode!]]
```

I'm using java 7 and play 2.2.6

Anyone have a clue of what is happening?

Comment: This is probably caused by having your client and service in the same project - see this by the author with his workaround - https://github.com/imindeu/play-cxf/issues/9

Comment: You could try using play 2.6 instead in which it seems the author of that tutorial has removed the workaround and probably fixed the issue - https://github.com/imindeu/play-cxf/tree/play-2.6.x/samples/play-cxf-hello